# set column value from two column variable

Tags: excel, vba

I write some code to find column header and change the index into column name, however, I cant combine these two variables into a column to replace column a value, following is my coding:

```
Sub BRRReport()

        Dim ColAN As Long, ColSD As Long, ColCombine As Long
        Dim ColLan As String, ColLsd As String
        ColAN = Application.Match("Football", Sheets("Sheets1").Rows(1), 0)
        ColSD = Application.Match("Baseball", Sheets("Sheets1").Rows(1), 0)
        ColLan = Split(Cells(1, ColAN).Address, "$")(1)
        ColLsd = Split(Cells(1, ColSD).Address, "$")(1)

        Debug.Print ColAN
        Debug.Print ColSD
        Debug.Print ColLan
        Debug.Print ColLsd

        Columns("A").Value = Columns(ColLan).Value + Columns(ColLsd).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting an error of some sort? What error and on what line? What are the variables equal to on that line when you get the error?

Comment: Side note: In `Dim ColAN, ColSD, ColCombine As Long`, only `ColCombine` is declared as `Long`. Use `As Long` after each variable name.

Comment: its the problem of Columns("A").Value = Columns(ColLan).Value + Columns(ColLsd).Value, if I change to single value its fine but I cant combine two variable value. And the error is type mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub BRRReport()
    Dim ColAN As Long, ColSD As Long, rw As Long, c As Range

    ColAN = Application.Match("Football", Sheets("Sheets1").Rows(1), 0)
    ColSD = Application.Match("Baseball", Sheets("Sheets1").Rows(1), 0)

    If Cells(Rows.Count, ColAN).End(xlUp).Row > Cells(Rows.Count, ColSD).End(xlUp).Row Then
        rw = Cells(Rows.Count, ColAN).End(xlUp).Row
    Else
        rw = Cells(Rows.Count, ColSD).End(xlUp).Row
    End If

    For Each c In Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(rw, 1))
        c.Value = Cells(c.Row, ColAN).Value & Cells(c.Row, ColSD)
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I solve it as belows:

Columns("A").Value = "=" & ColLan & "1" & "&" & ColLsd & "1"

Comment: My solution would give the same result except it wont fill every cell in column A with a formula